# Consider table has 4 user login-logout records for a day. I want to determine the login and logout separately

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, subquery, window-functions

I have below data

```
Emp.  Log data
A1.   20-JAN-2020 13:15:00
A1.   20-JAN-2020 12:00:00
A1.   20-JAN-2020 10:50:00
A1.   20-JAN-2020 07:00:00
```

From above, I want to derive login logout data. So 0700 AM is the first login, then lead time is the logout. Again the next log time is in time. Ie, 12:00:00

Expected result:

```
Emp   login                logout 
A1.   20-JAN-2020 07:00:00 20-JAN-2020 10:50:00
A1.   20-JAN-2020 12:00:00  20-JAN-2020 13:15:00
```

Comment: And what if a given log-in/log-out pair do not occur on the same day?  Say log in at 22:30 and log out at 01:30 the next day?  What if a log in or a log out somehow doesn't get recorded? (Don't say it can't happen).  I think your table design is flawed and you need to add a column to indicate if a specific activity is a log in or a log out.

Comment: Yes that happens. Thing is we have date field . Ie, attendance date. So I grouped with date and then apply the logic

Answer (score 5):

If you want to group rows by pairs, with the first row per group considered the login and the other as logout, you can use window functions as follows:

```
select emp, min(log_date) login, max(log_date) logout
from (select t.*, row_number() over(partition by emp order by log_date) rn from mytable t) t
group by emp, floor((rn - 1)/2)
```

Another option uses `lead()` and `mod()`:

```
select emp, log_date login, lead_log_date logout
from (
    select emp, log_date, 
        row_number()   over(partition by emp order by log_date) rn,
        lead(log_date) over(partition by emp order by log_date) lead_log_date
    from mytable 
) t
where mod(rn, 2) = 1
```